# How to write a subsetting operation in magrittr/dplyr: x[!is.na(x)]

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I am trying to convert the following idiom to use it in a magrittr functional sequence:

```
x[!is.na(x)]
```

x is any vector.

**Update:**

```
x %>% extract(!is.na(.))
```

That one is close, but still the operations `!` and `is.na` are not used in functional sequence. I look for something like:

```
x %>% extract(x %>% is.na %>% `!`)
```

All operations should be separated.

Comment: `x %>% extract(!is.na(.))`

Comment: Several people downvoted for this question. I would like to learn why they found this question not useful. So I will not repeat asking similar questions. I thought this question might be useful for R community because it is an interesting mental challenge.

Comment: A slight modification on your try could be: x %>% `[`(is.na(.) %>% `!`). An alternative, since you're referring to functional, could be `keep_non_NA = function(x) x[!is.na(x)]; x %>% keep_non_NA`.

Comment: @alexis_laz Thank you, that is what I was looking for: `x %>% '['(is.na(.) %>% '!')` The rules related to dot makes me confused sometimes. If you could write your reply as an answer, more people might benefit it.

Comment: This is a useful question imo : in particular I was also looking for details on how to use the `.` in _magrittr_

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` you could do:

```
x <- c(1,NA,NA,2,NA,3)

library(dplyr)
data.frame(x) %>% filter(!is.na(.))
```

Which gives:

```
#  x
#1 1
#2 2
#3 3
```

Or as mentionned by Khashaa in the comments

```
library(magrittr)
x %>% extract(!is.na(.))
```

Which gives:

```
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: That is close, but still the operations `!` and `is.na` are not used in functional sequence. I want to have something like: `x %>% extract(x %>% is.na %>% `!`)` So all operations should be separated.

Comment: @MertNuhoglu Clarify your problem further, why would you want code any longer?

Comment: How about `x %>% is.na %>% '!'  %>% extract(x, .)`?

Comment: @ExperimenteR that works but still there is one issue: is it possible to eliminate using `x` inside extract?

Comment: @zx8754 I am just trying to learn and discover the limits of magrittr way of expressions.